# Misspelling words for comedic effect

Tags: terminology

I would like to know the term-- if there is one-- for purposefully misspelling words for comedic effect.For example: a character in a story wishes to use the word "sublime," remembers only that it's sub + citrus fruit, says sublemonal (pronounced subliminal).

I have found reference to sensational spelling (doesn't quite capture the spirit) and to orthoepy / cacoepy (which I believe refers to pronunciation).

Thank you!

Comment: _Sublemonal_ would appear to be an almost subliminal pun.

Comment: Soonerism, sorry, spoonerisms. I don't have the inclination or the energy  to write an answer.

Comment: @Mari-LouA - You need to get yourself a cup of covfefe!

Comment: Why not say: misspelling words for comic effect? Is something wrong with that? comedic=refers to comedy; comic refers to something funny.

Comment: Is it really Spoonerism @Mari-LouA? I always thought Spoonerism was/is usually swapping the letters of words. My Dad was a great proponenent of that. A proponent! Should've thought of that word the other day. I think this example is more Mallapropism. My Grandma, was a great proponent of that! I remember her once announcing 'Oh! Look at that new building! It's been reburnished!!'

Comment: @ Jelila @Mari-LouA Okay! Thank you. I believe the term that bests describes what I am am doing (or rather what my character is doing) is malapropism (one "l"). From Random House unabridged (1993): malapropism an act or habit of misusing words ridiculously by confusion of words that are similar in sound; an instance of this. From Malaprop, a character in Sheridan's "The Rivals," noted for her misapplication of words. [Sorry haven't learned how to insert paragraphs. break yet.] In the grander scheme of the story this better captures what Missy (a talking dog) is doing.

Comment: The question's title does not match the example in the question's body. If anyone misspells anything, it's the author, not the character. And that title tacitly implies that the actual words are the same as the intended words. But the OP's example is of the character intending one word ("sublime"), misremembering it as "subliminal" and saying the latter. Which is it? If the latter, then Marica's answer "malapropism" is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @ Jelila and  @Mari-LouA in the comments for two possible answers. I believe the term that bests describes what I am doing (or rather what my character is doing) is malapropism (one "l").

From Random House unabridged (1993):

> "malapropism: an act or habit of misusing words ridiculously by
> confusion of words that are similar in sound; an instance of this."

From Malaprop, "a character in Sheridan's *The Rivals*, noted for her misapplication of words."

In the grander scheme of the story this better captures what Missy (a talking dog) is doing.

Comment: Yeah, no it's not a malapropism. A malapropism is misuse of one fancy word for another, not, as you desire, a humorous misspelling (intended or not). [eggcorn](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/eggcorn) is a  use of homophones in a phrase to give plausibly similar meaning to the original. Since that is a respelling (which indeed is a misspelling but to another legal word), that -may- be a single word for what you are looking for.